# Inline ads on sites that don't have Inline ads

Tags: virus

When using IE9 and Google Chrome inline ads are shown. But when I browse on another computer the ads are not there. I've ran MSE and it detected 2 alerts and I have removed them. I ran MBAM and it showed around 5 adware and then found PUP.PlaySushi which I can't seem to remove. Whenever I hover-over the ads PlaySushi pops up. How can I get rid of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [exterminate-it.com's "Malpedia"](http://www.exterminate-it.com/malpedia/remove-playsushi):

> PlaySushi Uninstallation
>
> PlaySushi software usually uninstalls using standard Windows Add or Remove Programs functionality. However, if you was not able to remove PlaySushi by the normal way, please try the following steps:
>
> 1. Download latest PlaySushi Uninstaller from the following location: http://www.playsushi.com/Remove.ps
> 2. Run PlaySushi Uninstaller and follow instructions (Click “Next” on first dialog window and then “Reboot” on second). Your PC should reboot after that.
> 3. After reboot PlaySushi software should be completely removed from your system.

The same link provides lots of information for manually removing PlaySushi's "Adware", hopefully it will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems of malware is that they can seriously hamper attempts to remove them. The nuclear option is always to reformat and reinstall your PC. However, before you do this, try [Spybot - Search & Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org) and [HijackThis.](http://free.antivirus.com/hijackthis/)